# High order functions in Scala

Tags: scala

IM trying to understand the below high order functions in Scala but need some clarifications on the parameters of the functions.

Questions:-

1. What does the `Int => String` in the `apply` function mean?
   `v: Int` indicates that the parameter v is of type `Int`.
2. What does the `[A](x: A)` mean in `layout` function?

   ```
    object Demo {
      def main(args: Array[String]) {
       println( apply( layout, 10) )
     }

      def apply(f: Int => String, v: Int) = f(v)

      def layout[A](x: A) = "[" + x.toString() + "]"
   }
   ```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`f: Int => String` means that `f` is a function with one argument of type `Int` and with a return type `String`

`def layout[A](x: A)` means that parameter `x` is of type `A`, which can be of any type. Here are a couple of examples on how to invoke layout:

```
layout[String]("abc") //returns "[abc]"
layout[Int](123)  //returns "[123]"
```

When `main` runs it invokes `apply` with the `layout` function and the argument 10. This will output `"[10]"`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `Int => String` means passing a function that accepts `Int` and returns `String`.

Here is a useful example for passing function:

```
case class Person(name: String, lastName: String)

val person = Person("Johnny", "Cage")

def updateName(name: String) = {
  updatePerson(_.copy(name = name))
}

def updateLastName(lastName: String) {
  updatePerson(_.copy(lastName = lastName))
}

private def updatePerson(transformer: Person => Person): Unit = {
  transformer(person)
```

}

Note how each `update` function passes the copy constructor.